# react native run-android failed after installing react-native-i18n

Tags: android, react-native, internationalization

good day everyone,
so i am working on this `react-native` project and thought about using `react-native-i18n` to support multiple languages in my application.

i installed the package with yarn:

`yarn add react-native-i18n`

then i linked it with `react-native link react-native-i18n`
and then reverified the android files manually following the installing guide on their github repo.

all the code works correctly but the application won't start. i was using android API 22 when i first tried so i thought it's maybe about the API version so i used the max version available which is API 28 but still same problem.

this is the error that i get on my metro server:

```
events.js:173
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'F:\Projects\pfe\front\android\app\build\intermediates\blame\res\debug\multi-v2'
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at NodeWatcher.<anonymous> (F:\Projects\pfe\front\node_modules\metro\node_modules\sane\src\node_watcher.js:291:16)
    at F:\Projects\pfe\front\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:282:31
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:159:21)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

and this is the error i get from run-android:

```
> Configure project :app
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

> Configure project :react-native-i18n
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: F:\Projects\pfe\front\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :react-native-i18n:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: F:\Projects\pfe\front\node_modules\react-native-i18n\android\src\main\java\com\AlexanderZaytsev\RNI18n\RNI18nModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets FAILED
Could not merge source set folders:
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: F:\Projects\pfe\front\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_assets\debug\mergeDebugAssets\out\fonts
        at com.android.ide.common.resources.MergeWriter.end(MergeWriter.java:52)
        at com.android.ide.common.resources.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:292)
        at com.android.ide.common.resources.AssetMerger.mergeData(AssetMerger.java:27)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeSourceSetFolders.doFullTaskAction(MergeSourceSetFolders.java:135)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeSourceSetFolders.doIncrementalTaskAction(MergeSourceSetFolders.java:163)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:110)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)

        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)

        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)

        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: F:\Projects\pfe\front\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_assets\debug\mergeDebugAssets\out\fonts
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1006)
        at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.close(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:56)
        at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.await(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:47)
        at com.android.ide.common.resources.MergeWriter.end(MergeWriter.java:48)
        ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: F:\Projects\pfe\front\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_assets\debug\mergeDebugAssets\out\fonts
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1005)
        ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: F:\Projects\pfe\front\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_assets\debug\mergeDebugAssets\out\fonts
        at com.android.ide.common.resources.MergedAssetWriter$AssetWorkAction.run(MergedAssetWriter.java:97)
        at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter$submit$submission$1.run(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:39)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: F:\Projects\pfe\front\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_assets\debug\mergeDebugAssets\out\fonts
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:504)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:781)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:767)
        at com.android.ide.common.resources.MergedAssetWriter$AssetWorkAction.run(MergedAssetWriter.java:84)
        ... 6 more

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to capture fingerprint of output files for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets' property 'outputDir' during up-to-date check.
> Could not read path 'F:\Projects\pfe\front\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_assets\debug\mergeDebugAssets\out\fonts'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
51 actionable tasks: 44 executed, 7 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

i know the error messages are way too long but i couldn't figure out which one to keep and which one to get rid of, so i hope you guys be kind enough to take a look at them and help me figure out this problem.
if i need to add any code please ask away, i didn't any parts because my android files are the same as the installation guide.

thank you all in advance for your time and help. have a great day.

Comment: Can you show me the code you applied?

Comment: i didn't apply any code i just installed the package. the only changes made are the ones made by the react-native link

Comment: Try applying it to the actual code and reloading it.

Comment: you mean implement the library inside the js code ?

Comment: That's right. you need try

Comment: ok i'll give it a try and tells you what happened

Comment: it worked, thanks for your help. if you want you can post an answer and i'll confirm it

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you've been helpful. I've posted `my answer`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying it to the actual code and reloading it.

example.js :

```js
// app/i18n/locales/en.js

export default {  
  greeting: 'Hi!'
};

// app/i18n/locales/fr.js

export default {  
  greeting: 'Bonjour!'
};

// app/i18n/i18n.js

import I18n from 'react-native-i18n';
import en from './locales/en';
import fr from './locales/fr';

I18n.fallbacks = true;

I18n.translations = {
  en,
  fr
};

export default I18n;

// usage in component

import I18n from 'app/i18n/i18n';

class Demo extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Text>{I18n.t('greeting')}</Text>
    )
  }
}
```

[Links](https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n) with a description of `i18n`